# What does a comma do in assignment statements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I found this in a piece of code and i'm wondering what it does? Assign b to x... but what's with the `,c`?

```
var x = b, c;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [\`x = y, z\` comma assignment in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769922/x-y-z-comma-assignment-in-javascript)

Comment: @DaggNabbit No, it's not the comma operator

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That declares two variables, `x` and `c`, and assigns value `b` to variable `x`.

This is equivalent to the more explicit form<sup>*</sup>:

```
var x = b;
var c;
```

JavaScript allows multiple declarations per `var` keyword – each new variable is separated by a comma. This is the style suggested by JSLint, which instructs developers to use a single var per function (the error message from JSLint is `Combine this with the previous 'var' statement.`).

<sup>* Actually, due to hoisting it will be interpreted as `var x; var c; x = b`.</sup>

Comment: A similar syntax is commonly seen in large for loops: `for(var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {}`

Comment: That's not actually a comma operator, surely? It's a declaration of multiple variables.

Comment: I think @stusmith is right. The separator for multiple variable declaration just happens to be the same symbol as the *comma operator*.

Comment: @stusmith, I believe it is. The assignment takes place first, then it returns `c`, which is just not used.

Comment: In the context of a `var` declaration, the comma is just a separator between the list of variable initializations. It's not the comma operator; even if it were, it wouldn't matter, as the `var` statement has no "value" anyway.

Comment: @Pointy, I agree with your "even if it were" part. I think it *is* the comma operator, as I couldn't find any other references to comma syntax in JS.

Comment: Operators exist at expression level, not statement level. `var a = (1, 2)` would be using the comma operator because `(1, 2)` is an expression. The comma in `var a = 1, b = 2` is not part of an expression. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: Thanks @pimvdb, your comment convinced me. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Note: my original answer said that this comma was the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). The debate on the comments showed me that is not the case. The comma in this case is part of the [syntax for the `var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), as pointed out by pimvdb. This answer was edited accordingly

Answer (score 5):

That defines two local variables `x` and `c` - while setting `x`'s value equal to the value of `b`.

Answer (score 5):

`c` is `undefined`.

This is equivalent:

```
var x = b;
var c;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's the same as

```
var x = b;
var c;
```

One of those so clever it's extremely stupid additions to a language.