# Javascript variable definition - clarification

Tags: javascript, variables, declaration

What does below declaration mean ?

```
var line = {}, lines = [], hasmore;
```

I understand that `lines = []` is an array , but I have no idea about the others.

Actual code is to reading file line by line using javascript xpcom

```
var line = {}, lines = [], hasmore;
do {
      hasmore = istream.readLine(line);
      lines.push(line.value); 
} while(hasmore);
```

Comment: Remember that JavaScript does not keep track of variable types at "compile-time." `x=[]; x=3; x="hi";` is perfectly valid (though not recommended.) The type of a variable is determined by how you use it, not how you declare it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does variable declaration with multiple comma separated values mean (e.g. var a = b,c,d;)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076750/what-does-variable-declaration-with-multiple-comma-separated-values-mean-e-g-v)

Comment: and [var myArray =\[\], name;?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6232778/218196)

Comment: and [What does a comma do in assignment statements in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9568905/218196)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's creating 3 variables

```
var line = {};   // creates an object
var lines = [];  // creates an array
var hasmore;     // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Declared 3 variables (see: [Declaring Multiple Variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/694102/1671639)).

```
var line = {}  // creates an empty object literal
    lines = [] // creates an empty array literal
    hasmore    // creates an empty undefined variable, which can hold any datatype
```

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and try this on your console :

```
var line = {}, lines = [], hasmore;
```

then access them you will see :

```
line is Object, 
lines is an array 
hasmore is undefined
```